# Desktop wont boot - No POST

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

## Problem Summary

My Desktop was working fine. Then, when I switched on my PC after an hour of halt, it won't boot. Initially, it showed me POST screen (Gigabyte logo with options to enter BIOS, Boot menu) with a single beep, then going to Gigabyte Dual Bios screen, then restarting, in a loop. Now, I don't even get the POST Screen.

## System Specs

- AMD Fx-8350 Processor
- Geforce GA-970A-DS3 motherboard
- 8Gb RAM
- Seagate 2TB Harddisk
- Cooler Master 400W PSU
- ZOTAC 610 Graphics card

## Description

I was working in my PC yesterday. Then shut it down for an hour or so. When I switched it on again, it showed the BIOS screen, with a single beep showing sign of successful POST, then just went to Gigabyte Dual BIOS screen. Then it restarted and then went to the same screen.

I looked up over the internet and found a similar [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/42a4df/stuck_on_gigabyte_uefi_dual_bios_screen/) and followed accordingly. But that did not help my case. From then onwards, I do not even get the BIOS screen.

## Things I tried

1. Swapped the components (RAM, PSU, Graphics Card) with another PC (a similar build - ASUS Sabertooth 990Fx R2.0 Motherboard with AMD Fx 8150 processor) and 8150 PC worked pretty well with these components. But my own 8350 did not work with the swapped components. So I ruled out the possibility that any of these three components might be malfunctioning.
2. Then, removed the RAM and switched on the PC - getting continuous short beeps.
3. Reinserted the RAM, removed the Video card from MoBo, but there is no beep sound
4. Removed the CMOS battery and reinserted it, as in the [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/42a4df/stuck_on_gigabyte_uefi_dual_bios_screen/), but that did not help my case. Also, tried resetting the BIOS with a jumper and that too did not work out.
5. Also plugged out and plugged in the power cables as well - no luck there.

Also, now I notice that the CPU fan turns off two to three seconds after I switch on my PC. (I don't remember this happening with my previous tries, but atleast this did not happen immediately in my previous tries)

Comment: Sounds like motherboard failure possibly due to overvoltage :(

Comment: @Florian pls tell me why you think so

Comment: Well obviously your bios is not booting, which means it's a low level hardware issue that's not related to your drives for example. Since you ruled out RAM, your PSU and video card, there aren't any more components that would cause this besides the MB itself having failed. Do you have any additional hardware installed? Like add in PCI cards ? If yes try to remove those too.

Comment: Also are you using a noname cheap PSU? If yes, it's much more likely to be that problem.

Comment: The CPU Fan starting then stopping after a very short delay is normally an indication of a short that exists.  As to the reason for your problems, it likely is hardware, due to the description the motherboard is the culprit.  *I have over 2 decades of working with a computer, I have had hundreds of problems over those years, conclusion is based on experience.*

Comment: @Florian I am using Cooler Master 400W PSU in the faulty one.

Comment: @Ramhound So the CPU might still be intact, even if the CPU fan stops immediately eh?

Comment: @Kenpachi - The CPU could be intact or it could be causing the short, of course since the behavior started before you touched the CPU, I doubt the CPU magically bent it's own pins.